# Javascript to detect start and end of AsyncPostback of specific Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, panel

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

       prm.add_endRequest(endRequest);
       prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);
       var _postBackElement;

       function initializeRequest(sender, e) 
       {
           if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) 
           {
               e.set_cancel(true);
           }

           _postBackElement = e.get_postBackElement();

           document.getElementById('loadingm').style.visibility = 'visible';
       }

     function endRequest(sender, e) 
           {
               $find('PopCustom_').show();
               document.getElementById('loadingm').style.visibility = 'hidden';  
           }
    </script>
```

This code will work on every AsyncPostback, but I want it to work Update-Panel specific.
Not being too familiar with JS, I don't know where I to do the modification.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution so far is:

```
var cmdAuthoriseButton ='<%= cmdAuthorise.ClientID %>'; 

function beginReq(sender, args){ 

   if (cmdAuthoriseButton == args._postBackElement.id)

   {

       // shows the Popup 

       $find(ModalProgress).show();        

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger of the start is pretty easy because something has to trigger it so you can always add code to whatever is triggering the refresh.

To trigger off of the completion of an `UpdatePanel` being refreshed is not as straight forward but the framework has provided some javascript functionality to help with this. The following javascript code will trigger off of an `UpdatePanel` refresh completing:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
prm.pageLoaded(YourJavascriptFunctionNameHere); 
//or
prm.add_pageLoaded(YourJavascriptFunctionNameHere);
```

Then implement the function you registered:

```
function YourJavascriptFunctionNameHere(sender, args)
{
    // do something
}
```

If you want you can use the same method to work off the start of the `UpdatePanel` refresh as well using

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
prm.beginRequest(YourJavascriptFunctionNameHere);
// or
prm.add_beginRequest(YourJavascriptFunctionNameHere);
```

I think you can figure out what element is causing the refresh from the `sender` or `args` params but you will need to read more about this function on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx).

**EDIT:** (from the MSDN article, an example of figuring out which `UpdatePanel` is refreshing)

```
function beginRequest(sender, args) {
    postbackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
}
function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
    var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
    if (typeof(postbackElement) === "undefined") {
        return;
    } 
    else if (postbackElement.id.toLowerCase().indexOf('external') > -1) {
        for (i=0; i < updatedPanels.length; i++) {            
            panelUpdatedAnimation.animatePanel(updatedPanels[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is that I want to use the code I entered above Update-Panel specific. (it currently fires on every AsyncPostback)

I guess I rather have to modfiy "var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();"

Comment: @dll32 inside of your handler I think you can identify which item caused the refresh so you could test that to determine whether or not to run the code.  The MSDN link shows more information about figuring that out.

Comment: Didn't think it would be that complex. 

Could there be a different solution starting from the UpdatePanel ID ??

Comment: @dll32 I don't think so because remember you are dealing with the framework provided by .net, you can't just start at a control since everything is built off the base objects created by the framework.  If you do find a better way please post it here but I think the above are the best tools at your disposal.